# Does Netbeans v8.0.2 plugin for cakephp support cakephp v3?

Tags: cakephp, netbeans, cakephp-3.0, netbeans-8, netbeans-plugins

I have been using Netbeans v8.0.2 and the cakephp plugin works perfectly fine on cakephp v2.x. Recently, I started a new project in cakephp v3.0.2 and the cakephp in Netbeans failed to recognize the project as cakephp.

Is it because cakephp v3.x is still not supported on Netbeans yet? If already supported, what are the configuration to take note to get it to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try https://github.com/junichi11/cakephp3-netbeans
Cake3 support is now a separate plugin.

Answer (score 3):

**https://github.com/junichi11/cakephp-netbeans**

> ### Environment
>
> - [...]
> - CakePHP 3.x (early support)
>
> ### About CakePHP 3.x
>
> Currently, This plugin doesn't recognize CakePHP3.

- **https://github.com/junichi11/cakephp-netbeans/issues/117**
- **https://github.com/junichi11/cakephp3-netbeans**